# Value weighted Portfolio: Include Market cap of pref shares?

Tags: equities, portfolio

I got Datastream MV data for my sample and i want to exclude Preference Shares. 
Since Datastreams definition of MV is shares*price there are two Marketvalues, one for common stock, one for preference Share.

I want to calculate value weighted Portfolios:

Shall i include the MV of the preference shares to weight my common stock, so its weight is based on its firm.

Or shall i just use the MV for the common stock. 
There are firms like VW that have like 60/40 common stock/preference shares, so it definitely matters.

Any recommendations ? What is the typical procedure in the Literature ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: This may have to be researched on a stock by stock basis: what do well known index providers do? I researched the case of Eurostoxx index https://www.stoxx.com/component-details?key=EG7 and VW. To my surprise only the preference shares of VW (DE0007664039) are included in the index, not the common. In most other cases I think it would be only the common shares. More research is needed.

Comment: ... I vaguely remember that most ordinary shares of VW are owned by one family, so they are not considered publicly available.... to be confirmed.

Comment: Researchers typically use CRSP Share Code 10,11 . So preference shares are excluded. However i don't know if they value weight their Portfolios by the company Market Cap or the common Stock market cap 
Interesting point with the Eurostoxx, would've thought the opposite would be true :D